# Mysql Procedure error while executing it

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6

I am creating procedure which selects member_id in courser.member_id having more that 100000 records. i had declared one variable i which stores one member id at time update it with next query.

can anyone resolve this..? procedure is as follows:-

```
    DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Mock_test_1;
CREATE PROCEDURE Mock_test_1()
   BEGIN
DECLARE i int unsigned;
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR select member_id from client_master;
open curs1;
read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH curs1 INTO i;
update client_master set
         `mobileno`='0000001231', 
         `email`=concat('MOCK',member_id,'@mock.com'), `password`=md5('MOCK'),
         `personaladdress` = concat('MOCK',member_id),
         businessaddress = concat('MOCK',member_id),
         imeino = '00000000000000', panno= 'AAAAA66666' ,aadharno = '11111111111111';
insert into client_master_test select * from client_master;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

can anyone suggest me blocker for this..?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: in your query you do not have any `where` clause. can you please explain the purpose of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

- You are fetching into `i`, but not using it.
- There is no end loop.
- The insert is copying the whole table over repeatedly?

Consider using a single multi-table UPDATE, not a Stored Procedure with a loop.